# posting direct form - checkboxes are ignrored

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm using the Ext.Direct.Mvc stack - when i submit a direct form - everything but the checkboxes get submitted correctly.

no matter what way they are checked they always get submitted as false?

has anyone seen this too?

w://

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?p=211041#post211041

simples